# Remineralization of ro water

Tags: solvents, minerals

Hello we are trying to prepare a solvent based solution of different kinds of minerals which can be added to reverse osmosis permeate water so that some of the essential minerals can be added back to the water. Do anyone knows which solvent we should use?

Comment: For future reference: be more specific with your questions. This one, with «different kinds of minerals», «some of the essential minerals», does not qualifies for such.

Comment: You really want to add a solvent back into drinking water???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think water is the best solvent, assuming you want to remineralise the RO water for drinking it. Your solution might become a slurry depending on the required volume. Have you considered simply using a solid mix of these minerals? A solid mix would allow for a more homogeneous mix of different minerals than a low volume liquid.